# My FactoryGirl created objects are not persisted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara, factory-bot

I am running the following feature:

```
  Scenario: viewing existing images
    Given I am on the images page
    And 4 images already exist
    Then I should see a table containg those 4 images
    And have the option to show images
    And have the option to delete images
```

with these steps defined:

```
Given /^I am on the images page$/ do
  visit(images_path)
end

Given /^(\d+) images already exist$/ do |count|
  count.to_i.times {
    FactoryGirl.build(:image).save!
  }
end

Then /^I should see a table containg those (\d+) images$/ do |count|
  page.all('table#imagesTable tr').count.should == count
end
```

The final step, counting the rows in the table, fails miserably. It can only find one row, which I assume is the header row. These are the tests for the index page, which I have manual confirmed it works. Why aren't my FactoryGirl created objects picked up my controller?

The index method of the controller:

```
  def index
    @images = Image.all
  end
```

Comment: Try swapping the order of the 'I am on the images page' and '4 images already exist' givens. I reckon the index action is being called before creating the images, and so the new images aren't actually being picked up

Comment: @SuperMaximo93 Cheers, you nailed it. Submit an answer if you want the credit :)

Comment: Cool :) Answer submitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the order of the 'I am on the images page' and '4 images already exist' givens.

The index action is being called the view is rendered before the creation of the images, so they they won't be picked up.

Also, I don't know if you know this already, but instead of

```
FactoryGirl.build(:image).save!
```

you can do

```
FactoryGirl.create(:image)
```

Comment: Already done that. You learn so many things when reading the documentation :)

Comment: And I wasted 3-4 hours trying to debug a test, just because I used `build` except `create`. I guess, one reading the docs is not enough :)